# Supporting voice and touch commands in Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

After following the tutorial provided by Google itself still only voice commands are recognized.

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice?hl=de#voice-and-touch

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View testView = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.TEXT)
        .setText("test123")
        .getView();     

    getWindow().requestFeature(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL);
    setContentView(testView);   
}

@Override
public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if (featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS ||
            featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_one, menu);
        return true;
    }
    // Pass through to super to setup touch menu.
    return super.onCreatePanelMenu(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    if (featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS || 
            featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_one_item:
                //Some stuff
                //...
                break;
            default:
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

Is it really enough to just check for `FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL` or is it necessary to add an `onClick` listener of some sort? Maybe it's just me having trouble understanding the instructions the way intended.

The tutorial is from July 31st, is it possible the API has changed since then and they haven't updated their post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to somehow detect a tap so that when a user taps, your app shows the menu.

Example:

```
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGestureDetector = createGestureDetector(this);
}

private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context);

    gestureDetector.setBaseListener(new GestureDetector.BaseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGesture(Gesture gesture) {
            // if the user taps, play a proper sound and open the menu.
            // you might don't need the || gesture == Gesture.LONG_PRESS
            if (gesture == Gesture.TAP || gesture == Gesture.LONG_PRESS) {
                AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audio.playSoundEffect(Sounds.TAP);
                openOptionsMenu();
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    });
    return gestureDetector;
}

@Override
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mGestureDetector != null) {
        return mGestureDetector.onMotionEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I just tried exactly what you suggested but still nothing seems to happen. Using the onClick method however does work. 

On a side note: Eclipse shows a compiler warning stating that `mGestureDetector` declared at the very beginning is never used.

Thoughts?


Edit: Removed code as I couldn't get it to format correctly

Comment: add onGenericMotionEvent. i forgot it